# How to prefill voyager BREAD form with currently logged in user?

Tags: php, json, laravel, voyager

[SOLVED]
I have a simple listing in my laravel 5.7 project,and used voyager to manage its data.
and i want to make a fully working *created_by* and *last_edit_by* BREAD table but still have no idea to get the currently logged in user.

i currently using custom views(resources/views/vendor/voyager) with copy-pasted original codes,but still using original VoyagerBreadController.php with some additional import.

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Auth\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Wisata;
use App\User;

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Voyager;

use TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBreadController as BaseVoyagerBreadController;

class VoyagerBreadController extends BaseVoyagerBreadController
{
    //
}
```

and able to do this on my custom view

```
//get currently logged user
@php
  $currentUser = Auth::user()->nama;
@endphp

//printed output(for testing)
 {{$currentUser}}
```

and it works!,so i tried to set the BREAD option like this

```
{
    "default" : "{{$currentUser}}"
}
```

however,unlike my custom views it doesn't returned the $currentUser value,just plain {{$currentUser}} in my tables.

please help me to make a fully functional *created_by* and *last_edit_by* table.

notes: im open to use any packages.

EDIT : it's solved by duplicating the form just below the real dynamic form in my custom view(edit-add.blade.php),make a hidden type *created_by* & *last_edited_by* table & keep the BREAD option empty. and you can still adjust the visiblity without any problems.

```
//created_by form
<div class="form-group hidden  col-md-12 "><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="created_by" placeholder="Created By" value="{{$currentUser}}"></div>
//last_edited_by form
<div class="form-group hidden  col-md-12 "><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="last_edited_by" placeholder="Last Edited By" value="{{$currentUser}}"></div>
```

anyway , i still would be very thankful if someone give more efficient solution :)

Comment: Hi did you manage to solve this issue? I am currently suffering from this problem.

Comment: @Lito, I have added an answer please check and let me know if any issues with the method..

Answer (score 3):

You can add additional properties to the model without changing anything in the view file.

Just add the `save()` method in the corresponding Model class and assign additional properties.

**Model**

```php
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    if (Auth::user()) {
        $this->created_by = Auth::user()->getKey();
        //you may use user's name or any other property
        $this->updated_by = Auth::user()->name;
    }

    return parent::save();
}
```

This will add `created_by` and `updated_by` whenever saving the new model record. You may add additional logic to the `save()` method as per your need.

Tested in Laravel 8 [and should be work in 5.7 too]